# The Barisieur Coffee Alarm and Coffee ground freshness

Tags: flavor, ground-coffee, freshness

[The Barisieur Coffee and Tea Alarm Clock](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/393281213/the-barisieur-designer-coffee-and-tea-alarm-clock) (*pictured below*) is quite a novel spin on the conventional alarm clock where before one goes to sleep they set up the alarm by putting water in the beaker and coffee in the filter, whereupon in the morning they awake to a fresh cup of coffee

[image]

## My question

Won't leaving coffee grinds out overnight cause the coffee brewed the next day to be bland in the morning? This being said is there any way to have the coffee in there without it becoming bland overnight?

Answer (score 1):

Define bland...

If you compare just-ground to ground last evening and left open, yes, as a connoisseur you will probably notice a difference.

Comparing store-bought pre-ground coffee, a few hours in the open won’t matter too much.

Plus, there are a few minor issues that may outweigh the “freshness” question: Morning breath? Being half-awake? Before the caffeine kicks in, I, for example, am in a somewhat zombie-mode. If it smells like coffee, I will probably drink it... Leaving the finer brews for a time when I can appreciate them.